# VS 2015 Debug HLSL for XNA project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, xna-4.0, hlsl

I'm trying to use the HLSL Shader Debugger which I believe is apart of Visual Studio 2015 to debug some shader code I've written for an XNA 4.0 project. When I start the Graphics debugging session the target application runs like normal but the graphics diagnostics window does not appear to record any data till after the target application exits. Also regardless of if the the target application is running or not I can not capture any frames, the options to remains grayed out.

If any info on the problem I'm trying to debug would help let me know and I'll add what i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it seems this isn't available for us XNA developers since it only supports DirectX 11. [Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2014/04/05/gpu-profiling-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2/)

> **Shawn Hargreaves - MSFT April 9, 2014 at 7:58 am**
>
> This tooling supports
>   desktop as well as store apps, but it's only for D3D11 while XNA uses
>   D3D9.
>
> Xbox One has its own somewhat different version of PIX, which does
>   many similar things but in a more hardware specific way  (many things
>   get easier, and some richer types of data can be obtained, when you
>   don't have to worry about supporting more than one type of GPU with
>   different drivers!)